# How to keep html sliders consistent, in sync?

Tags: javascript, html, razor, range

I have a problem with keeping sliders in sync.
[Sliders preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEFvT.png)

If I +1 on one of the four sliders, then the others must be substracted with 1/3.
What is the best way to perform this action?

I tried through Javascript already but can't come up with a working code. The selected slider does change value, but the 3 others give weird numbers.

The oninput() method is called when changing one of the sliders. When selecting a sliders and pressing the arrows keys to change the value then nothing happens. When drag and dropping a new value on the slider, also nothing happens. Only when sliding very rapidly.
When clicking on a new value on the slider, it does work somehow..

What am I doing wrong here?

this is the whole function, some variables are written in Dutch...
Code preview:

```
function showValueSub(sliderValue, parent, aantalKinderen, totaalbedragCategorie, echteParentId, teller, aantalSiblings, opgeroepenDoorHoofdCategorie) {
/*
    het labeltje onder de afbeelding van de hoofdcategorie moet niet meer worden aangepast.
document.getElementById("subcat" + range).innerHTML = newValue + " Euro";
##
Parameters:
parent=het begrotingsId van het huidig element.
echteParentId= het begrotingsId van de parent
##
*/
//alert('test');

//###################################################################################################################################################
//#LOOPEN OVER DE SIBLINGS
//enkel loopen over siblings als deze functie wordt uitgevoerd door huidig element, en niet de parent.
//eerst het outputelement onder de slider aanpassen
var siblingElement = document.getElementById(echteParentId + "input" + teller);
if (siblingElement != null) var siblingSlider = parseInt(siblingElement.getAttribute("onchangeviaparent"));
if (siblingElement != null && siblingSlider != 1) {
    //als het niet is opgeroepen door een hoofdcategorie: dan output en input aanpasen van huidig element
    var huidigOutputElement = document.getElementById(echteParentId + "output" + teller);
    huidigOutputElement.innerText = sliderValue;
    var aantalAanpasbareSiblings = 0;
    var teVerdelenBedragSiblings = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < aantalSiblings - 1; i++) {
        var siblingElement = document.getElementById(echteParentId + "." + i);
        //tellen hoeveel kindelementen er zijn die aanpasbaar zijn.        
        if (siblingElement.getAttribute("categoriestatus") != "NIET_AANPASBAAR")
            aantalAanpasbareSiblings++;
    }
    if (aantalAanpasbareSiblings == 0) aantalAanpasbareSiblings = 1;
    if (vorigeSliderValueSibling != null)
        teVerdelenBedragSiblings = (sliderValue - vorigeSliderValueSibling) / aantalAanpasbareSiblings; //te verdelen bedrag per aanpasbaar siblingElement
    else
        teVerdelenBedragSiblings = Math.round(sliderValue / aantalAanpasbareSiblings).toFixed(2); //te verdelen bedrag per aanpasbaar siblingElement
    for (var i = 0; i < aantalSiblings; i++) {
        //het huidig subelement mag niet aangepast worden, checken met een if.
        var siblingElement = document.getElementById(echteParentId + "." + i);
        if (siblingElement != document.getElementById(echteParentId + "." + teller)) {
            if (siblingElement.getAttribute("categoriestatus") != "NIET_AANPASBAAR") {
                //in het p element staat een bedrag + de string "EURO".
                //eigen p element ophalen
                var siblingElementMetBedrag = document.getElementById(echteParentId + "." + i + "p");
                var bedrag = parseFloat(siblingElementMetBedrag.innerHTML.substring(0, siblingElementMetBedrag.innerHTML.length - 5).trim());
                bedrag -= teVerdelenBedragSiblings; //aftrekken ipv optellen
                siblingElementMetBedrag.innerHTML = Math.round(bedrag).toFixed(2) + " Euro";
                //siblinginput(slider) element ophalen en proberen aan te passen
                var siblingSliderElement = document.getElementById(echteParentId + "input" + i);
                if (siblingSliderElement != null) siblingSliderElement.value = Math.round(siblingSliderElement.value - teVerdelenBedragSiblings).toFixed(2);
                //output van sibling aanpassen
                var siblingSliderOutput =document.getElementById(echteParentId + "output" + i);
                if (siblingSliderOutput != null)
                    siblingSliderOutput.value = Math.round(siblingSliderOutput.value - teVerdelenBedragSiblings).toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    }
}
vorigeSliderValueSibling = sliderValue;
//###################################################################################################################################################
//#LOPEN OVER DE KINDEREN.
var aantalAanpasbareKinderen = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < aantalKinderen; i++) {
    var kindElement = document.getElementById(parent + "." + i);
    //tellen hoeveel kindelementen er zijn die aanpasbaar zijn.        
    if (kindElement.getAttribute("categoriestatus") != "NIET_AANPASBAAR")
        aantalAanpasbareKinderen++;
}
//als er geen aanpasbarekinderen gevonden zijn, deze standaard op 1 zetten want
//delen door 0 gaat niet.
if (aantalAanpasbareKinderen == 0) aantalAanpasbareKinderen = 1;
//checken of de slider al een keer is aangepast, zo ja huidig bedrag van de slider verminderen met vorige waarde van de slider
if (vorigeSliderValueSub != null)
    teVerdelenBedrag = (sliderValue - vorigeSliderValueSub) / aantalAanpasbareKinderen; //te verdelen bedrag per aanpasbaar kindElement
else
    teVerdelenBedrag = Math.round(sliderValue / aantalAanpasbareKinderen).toFixed(2); //te verdelen bedrag per aanpasbaar kindElement
for (var i = 0; i < aantalKinderen; i++) {
    var kindElement = document.getElementById(parent + "." + i);
    if (kindElement.getAttribute("categoriestatus") != "NIET_AANPASBAAR") {
        //in het p element staat een bedrag + de string "EURO".
        //eigen p element ophalen
        var kindElementMetBedrag = document.getElementById(parent + "." + i + "p");
        var bedrag = parseFloat(kindElementMetBedrag.innerHTML.substring(0, kindElementMetBedrag.innerHTML.length - 5).trim());
        bedrag += teVerdelenBedrag;
        kindElementMetBedrag.innerHTML = bedrag + " Euro";
        //kindinput element ophalen en proberen aan te passen
        var kindSliderElement = document.getElementById(parent + "input" + i);
        if (kindSliderElement != null) kindSliderElement.value = sliderValue / aantalAanpasbareKinderen;
    }
}
//###################################################################################################################################################
vorigeSliderValueSub = sliderValue;
//alert(siblingSlider.innerHTML);
if (siblingSlider != null) {
    $("#" + echteParentId + "input" + teller).attr('onchangeviaparent', '0');
    //siblingSlider.onchangeviaparent = '0';
    //alert(parseInt(siblingSlider.getAttribute("onchangeviaparent")));
}
//document.getElementById(echteParentId + "." + teller).setAttribute("onchangeViaParent", "0");
//alert(document.getElementById(echteParentId + "input" + teller).getAttribute("onchangeViaParent"));
```

}

Comment: not posting your code is what you're doing wrong. Ideally a working fiddle showing the problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] so we can see your script in action.